# Overridden function not receiving data?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, overriding

In my simple app *Bluetooth Tutorial* I connect a bluetooth scan gun and receive scans from it in the form of strings. I have all of the connecting code in `MainActivity`, and now all I am trying to do is Override my `receiveScans(String s)` function in another activity so that I can use the data for other purposes. However, the `receiveScans(String s)` always gets called in the `MainActivity` activity and never hits in the `TestingScanner` activity. Why is this? What do I need to do?

Here is the bit of code - my `Handler` - in `MainActivity` that sends the data that was scanned in into my `receiveScans()` function in `MainActivity`.

```
private MessageHandler mHandler = new MessageHandler();
private class MessageHandler extends android.os.Handler{
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what){
            case MESSAGE_READ: // Received scan, get information...
                byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                String scan = new String(readBuf);
                receiveScans(scan); // Send string of info to recieveScans
                break;
            default:
                super.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    }
}

protected void receiveScans(String s){

}
```

And here is the `TestingScanner` class that I amtrying to Override the receiveScans function in. I am simply trying to set the text in a `TextView` according to the string the scanner sent.

```
public class TestingScanner extends MainActivity {

TextView scannerText ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test_scanner);
    scannerText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.scanner_text);

}

@Override
protected void receiveScans(String s) {
    super.receiveScans(s);
    scannerText.setText(s);
}
}
```

The overridden function never gets called.

Comment: The override function will only be called if the TestingScanner activity is the current activity (or the activity in focus).

Comment: This is unclear. `TestingScanner` does not extend `MessageHandler`, so it's not clear why you think `TestingScanner.receiveScans()` should be called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling receiveScans()from MainActivity so receiveScans() of MainActivity will be called. From MainActivity (Base class) you will not be able to call receiveScans() of TestingScanner (Derived class), unless you create an object of TestingScanner and invoke receiveScans() on that object.